# Two way trust Exchange mailbox creation

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013

We have a two way trust between Domain A and Domain B. They are both Windows Server 2012 R2. Domain A has Exchange 2013 on it for the use of Domain A users. We want to create user mailboxes from Domain B on Domain A. Is this possible without creating new AD users on Domain A?

Answer (score 1):

You can create linked mailboxes in Domain A for the users in Domain B.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj673532(v=exchg.150).aspx